# How to get rid of SwifTUI List weird animation and spacing triggered by EditMode?

Tags: list, swiftui, transition, divider, editmode

If you create a new project on Xcode 12.5 and use a SwiftUI `List` combined to a `foreach` and `.onmove`, you will notice 2 annoying things:

1/ Even though ondelete is unset, and even though you explicitly specify `.deleteDisabled(true)`, a space appears on the left side of the list row when in EditMode. Is it possible to get rid of it?

2/ The entrance of the move icon creates some kind of an animation glitch on each list row. The divider is highlighting that. Why is there a space after the divider when EditMode is triggered? It seems that back in the past the divider width stay unchanged during this transition.

If you ask me, the previous behavior was making me think that the move button was embedded in a ZStack wrapping both the move button and the list. Whereas now it looks like it's in an HStack. Whatever, none of that explains the glitch which doesn't appear on the left side of the row even though it gets pushed too.

I am so confused.

I am surprised I am not able to find anything about that issue via Google. I am the one doing something wrong?

A video of the problem: [Glitch](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lvptswg2yzcwlvy/glitch.mov?dl=0) and here is a simple code to try it out yourself.

Thank you for your time.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var listItems = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(listItems, id: \.self) { (item) in
                    Text(item)
                }.onMove { (indexSet, index) in
                    self.listItems.move(fromOffsets: indexSet,
                                        toOffset: index)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Nav Title"))
            .deleteDisabled(true)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `.navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())` with `.toolbar { EditButton() }`. I can't find where it says so, but I think `EditButton` only works inside `toolbar`.

Comment: I'm still seeing this behavior on 15.0.1.

Comment: @arsenius I have a quick fix at least regarding the animation glitch, until Apple fix the issue. Use .animation(nil) on the list rows.